# WPF/C# Numbers in TextBox Calculated Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, binding, textbox

OK, so I am pretty sure I'm on the right track with this small application, but let me know.  The user enters in 3 of the 4 numbers into the 4 editable textboxes, and the missing number is calculated automatically.  Picture of app here:

http://www.peauproductions.com/images/lens_app.PNG

I have looked at data binding, and I think I need to have the values able to globally change.  I want the values to dynamically update/compute and not have to have a calculate button.

Once I get it working I need to implement a validation check to make sure a boolean is only entered (no text), and have a tooltip pop up saying to enter a number.

Getting the following ERROR right now:

**"'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Text' threw an exception.' Line number '56' and line position '51'."**

MainWindow.xaml Code:

```
<Window x:Class="ConverterApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ConverterApp" Height="360" Width="280"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ConvertorApp;assembly=">

<Grid>
    <!--Outer Box + Title-->
    <TextBox Height="309" Width="248"
    Text=" Lens Calculator"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Margin="5,5,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    BorderThickness="2.0"
    FontSize="16" FontFamily="Verdana" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush> 
    </TextBox>

    <!--Title Text-->
    <TextBox Height="50" Width="230"
    Text="Enter Image Width, Length and Either Distance or Lens Values Below"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Margin="14,29,0,0"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontSize="12" FontFamily="Verdana"  FontStyle="Italic"
    BorderThickness="0">        
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox Height="20" Width="230"
    Text="Must Be Same Units (in,ft,cm,mm)"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Margin="14,59,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontSize="10" FontFamily="Verdana" FontStyle="Italic"
    BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>

    <!--Distance-->
    <TextBox Height="20" Width="105"
    Text="Distance/Height:"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Margin="15,80,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontFamily="Verdana"
    BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox x:Name="DistanceBox" Height="20" Width="50"
    Text="{x:Static c:Variables.DistanceBox}"
    Margin="125,80,0,0"
    MaxLength="5" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontFamily="Verdana">
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
    </TextBox>

    <!--Image Width-->
    <TextBox Height="20" Width="90"
    Text="Image Width:"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Margin="15,105,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontFamily="Verdana"
    BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox x:Name="WidthBox" Height="20" Width="50"
    Text="{x:Static c:Variables.WidthBox}"
    Margin="125,105,0,0"
    MaxLength="5" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             FontFamily="Verdana">
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
    </TextBox>

    <!--Image Length-->
    <TextBox Width="95"
    Text="Image Length:"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Margin="15,130,0,161" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontFamily="Verdana"
    BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox x:Name="LengthBox" Height="20" Width="50"
    Text="{x:Static c:Variables.LengthBox}"
    Margin="125,130,0,0"
             MaxLength="5" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             FontFamily="Verdana">
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
    </TextBox>

    <!--Lens Needed-->
    <TextBox Height="20" Width="90"
    Text="Lens (mm):"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Margin="15,155,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontFamily="Verdana"
    BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox x:Name="LensNeeded" Height="20" Width="50"
    Text="{x:Static c:Variables.LensNeeded}"
    Margin="125,155,0,0"
             MaxLength="4" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             FontFamily="Verdana">
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
    </TextBox>

    <!--Info-->
    <TextBox Height="70" Width="230"
    Text="The lens focal length value represents the estimated mm value for a 1/4 inch sensor (Playstation Eye).  A lower mm will give a wider Field of View (FOV), and a higher value less FOV. "
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Margin="15,180,0,0"
    FontSize="11"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontFamily="Verdana"  FontStyle="Italic"
    BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Height="55" Width="230"
    Text="It is not recommend you use a lens of less than 2.5mm focal length with image tracking software due to distortion."
    IsReadOnly="True"
    FontSize="11"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Margin="15,253,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontFamily="Verdana"  FontStyle="Italic"
    BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>


</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace ConvertorApp
{
    public class Variables
    {
        public const double DistanceBox = 0;
        public const double WidthBox = 0;
        public const double LengthBox = 0;
        public const double LensNeeded = 0;
        public const double WidthBased = 0;
        public const double LengthBased = 0;

        public void Calc()
        {
            double WidthBased = 2.952*(DistanceBox/WidthBox);
            double LengthBased = 3.984*(DistanceBox/LengthBox);

            if (WidthBased < LengthBased)
            {
                double LensNeeded = WidthBased;
            }else{
                double LensNeeded = LengthBased;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you can think of an easier, or more correct way to go about what I'm trying to do, please let me know (I just started learning this WPF/C# stuff).  Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the back code showing suggested changes from below:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ConverterApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Variables();
        }
    }

    public class Variables : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Declare the PropertyChanged event.
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private double m_distanceBox;
        public double DistanceBox
        {
            get { return m_distanceBox; }
            set
            {
                m_distanceBox = value;
                // modify calc to read the text values
                Calc();
                // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
                // is updated.
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DistanceBox");
            }
        }

        private double m_widthBox;
        public double WidthBox
        {
            get { return m_widthBox; }
            set 
            {
                m_widthBox = value;
                // modify calc to read the text values
                Calc();
                // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
                // is updated.
                NotifyPropertyChanged("WidthBox");
            }  
        }

        private double m_lengthBox;
        public double LengthBox
        {
            get { return m_lengthBox; }
            set
            {
                m_lengthBox = value;
                // modify calc to read the text values
                Calc();
                // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
                // is updated.
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LengthBox");
            } 
        }

        private double m_lensBox;
        public double LensNeeded
        {
            get { return m_lensBox; }
            set
            {
                m_lensBox = value;
                // modify calc to read the text values
                Calc();
                // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property 
                // is updated.
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LensNeeded");
            } 
        }

        public void Calc()
        {
            double WidthBased = 2.95 * (DistanceBox / WidthBox);
            double LengthBased = 3.98 * (DistanceBox / LengthBox);

            if (WidthBased < LengthBased)
            {
                LensNeeded = Math.Round(WidthBased,2);
            }else{
                LensNeeded = Math.Round(LengthBased,2);
            }
        }

        // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event, 
        // passing the source property that is being updated.
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

****ERROR I'm now getting is the StackOverflowException on the get {} inside the double functions. Any ideas?**

Comment: What is the `InnerException` of the exception?

Comment: Your .cs code probably doesn't do what you think it does. The line `double LensNeeded = WidthBased;` creates a new variable called `LensNeeded`, which is discarded right after that line, because you don't use it.

Comment: @svick Please see updated code-behind.  Still don't know where to add the DataContext.  Errors keep popping up when I put it in the code-behind.  Thanks

Comment: You must've deleted the C# code of MainWindow. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's most likely because the namespaces of C# code and XAML code for `MainWindow` must match. You have `ConverterApp` in XAML, but `ConvertorApp` in C#.

Comment: @svick I'm getting a StackOverflowException error on the get functions on the public string functions. Would declaring an initial value for the 4 strings fix it?  How would I do that?

Comment: I think it would be better if you asked a new question. Anyway, of course you're getting that exception, when you're calling the getter for `DistanceBox` inside itself.

Comment: Ok, changes made but still same error, see code above.  I think the question still is valid as I'm yet to get the values to dynamically change.  Thanks for all your help so far though

Comment: New question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325909/wpf4-c-system-stackoverflowexception-crashing-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown because the line

```
Text="{x:Static c:Variables.DistanceBox}"
```

is effectively something like

```
textBox.Text = Variables.DistanceBox;
```

This wouldn't compile in C#. In XAML, it throws exception. What you should do instead is create properties from your fields:

```
public double DistanceBox { get; set; }
```

And set `Variables` as `DataContext` of your window, by adding

```
DataContext = new Variables();
```

to the constructor of your window (or handler of the `Loaded` event).

You then use bindings in your XAML (which uses a converter to make `string`s out of `double`s):

```
Text="{Binding DistanceBox}"
```

To call `Calc()` whenever a value changes, you can change the property to

```
private double m_distanceBox;
public double DistanceBox
{
    get { return m_distanceBox; }
    set
    {
        m_distanceBox = value;
        Calc();
    }
}
```

To make sure changes in `Variables` are reflected in the text boxes, you should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

**EDIT:** C# code of `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindw()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Variables();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I followed most of what you said. Where does the DataContext = new Variables(); go?  I'm thinking in a <Windows.Resource> in the top of my.xaml correct? Can you show how it should look?

Comment: Ok, so if I put your updated code in the namespace and right above the Variables class, I get the InitializeComponent(); doesn't exist error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set text ? In wpf you need to use invoke method insted of of setting direct text property.

Answer (score 0):

Your make mistake in setting text values:

```
YourTextBox.Text=YourValue;
```

in your case:

```
LensNeeded.Text = WidthBased.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use data binding for your text boxes.

1. Modify your Variables class to exposes the 4 values as string properties (you cannot databind to fields, only properties):

   ```
   public class Variables
   {
       // code as in your example
       public string LensValueNeeded 
       { 
         get { return LensNeeded.ToString(); }
         set { Calc(); }  // modify calc to read the text values
       }

       /// same for the other 3 values
   }
   ```

   Make sure that you modify your Calc method to read the current values from the TextBox as the data binding is setup to be two-way. You will need to convert the string values back to a double using the double.Parse() method:

   double d = double.Parse(stringValue);
2. Set the DataContext of your Grid to an instance of your Variables class
3. Bind the text of your TextBox to the string property:

   ```
   Text = {Binding LensNeededValue}
   ```

Comment: If I convert the values in the TextBox to Strings in the Variables class, it says I can't preform my calculations in the Calc() since they are Strings now.  How do I read the values so I can calculate?

Comment: You will need to read the string values and convert them to double, some thing like double d = double.Parse(stringValue). I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got that part fixed.  See updated behind-code in first post.  Thanks